# Proving that a matrix transformation maps the zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ into the zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Suppose $T: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is a matrix transformation. I want to show that

$$T(\vec{0}) = \vec{0}$$

I was told as a hint that we need to use the [linearity conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity) to make such a deduction, but I think that might be unnecessary, or I may be misunderstanding the concept of matrix transformations altogether.

Since $T$ is a matrix transformation, then for every $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ there exists a unique $m \times n$ matrix $A$ such that

$$T(\vec{x}) = A \cdot \vec{x}$$

If we let $\vec{x} = \vec{0}$, where this zero vector has dimensions $n \times 1$, then

$$T(\vec{0}) = A \cdot \vec{0} = \vec{0}$$

where the $\vec{0}$ on the right hand side of the equation is an $m \times 1$ vector.

Hence, every transformation maps the zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to the zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Are there any problems with the proof?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you've simply restated the question. You are asked to show that $T(0)=0$ where $T$ is given by $T(x)=Ax$. To do so you must justify *why* $A0=0$.

You have several options, but the best by far is to use the linearity of $T$.

Note that 
$$
T(0)=T(0-0)=T(0)-T(0)=0
$$
and you're done!

This is a great example of why abstraction is useful.

Comment: Heh, was in the process of writing an answer that was very nearly the same as this, but you were faster :). The OP can also prove their claim by noting that the entries of $A \cdot \vec{0}$ are given by the dot product of each of the rows of $A$ with $\vec{0}$, and hence are all $0$, but I agree that the abstract way is better.

Comment: @Brian_Fitzpatrix I guess I'm a little confused as to why it must be justified that $A \vec{0} = \vec{0}$ since this is a well established truth concerning matrix multiplication. I'm new to the concept of matrix transformations, but bear with me. To me, a given matrix transformation on $\vec{x}$ is synonymous with the matrix multiplication $A \vec{x}$ where $A$ is the standard matrix. Why is it that, in this case, the linearity conditions are what are needed for this proof? Also, in your proof, how do you know that $T(\vec{0}) = \vec{0}$?

Comment: @BenedictVoltaire This question is asking you to verify that $A0=0$. Simply saying that this is a "well established truth" is circular. Note that AlexWertheim's comment gives direct justification why $A0=0$.

Comment: Alright, but in the same section of the problem, there is a theorem which says, "For every matrix $A$, the matrix transformation $T_A:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ has the property $T_A(\vec{0}) = \vec{0}$," and the proof refers to a previous theorem regarding matrix multiplication that $A \vec{0} = \vec{0}$. It seems that this problem is asking for another proof using the linearity conditions, but I don't see why such a proof is necessary.

Comment: @BenedictVoltaire Later you'll learn about a more general concept called *linear transformations*. Every linear transformation $T$ satisfies $T(0)=0$ but is not necessarily of the form $T(x)=Ax$ for a matrix $A$. The only way to prove $T(0)=0$ is using the linearity conditions. So, not only is the proof I offer much simpler than writing the details your book provides, but it is also more general.